# making a gradient background color for a scatter dot chart

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to make a gradient background color for the scatter dot chart but I couldn't do it. Any help will be appreciated.Here is my code;

```
const gradientBackgroundColor={
    id:'gradientBackgroundColor',
    beforeDraw(chart,args,plugins){
        const{ctx,chartArea:{top,bottom,left,right,width,height}}=chart;
        const gradientBg=ctx.createLinearGradient(left,0,width,0);
        gradientBg.addColorStop(0, 'lightgreen');
        gradientBg.addColorStop(0.3, 'green');
        gradientBg.addColorStop(0.6, 'yellow');
        gradientBg.addColorStop(0.9, 'red');
        gradientBg.addColorStop(1, 'darkred');
        ctx.save();
        ctx.fillStyle=gradientBg
        ctx.fillRect(left,top,width,height)
    }
}
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'scatter',
     data: {
        labels: Array.from({length: chartData.length}, (_, i) => chartData[i]).map(item => item.title),
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Risks',
            labels: Array.from({length: chartData.length}, (_, i) => chartData[i]).map(item => item.title),
            data: chartData,
            pointRadius: 10,
            pointHoverRadius: 30
        }]
    },
    options: {
        plugins: [gradientBackgroundColor],
```

Comment: `plugins: [gradientBackgroundColor]` should not be under `options`, but at the top of the configuration object, at the same level as `type`, `data` or `options`